# Can't connect near-cli with near in local mode

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I ran indexer in local mode as a docker container and also had a container with near-cli.

```
sudo docker run -it --name indexer --rm -v indexer_data:/near indexer run
sudo docker run --name near-cli --rm -it --volumes-from indexer:ro near-cli bash
```

Both are in the same network. All configured fine.

How can I make a request from near-cli container to the indexer? I try to do something like inside near-cli container:

```
NEAR_ENV=local NEAR_NODE_URL=http://indexer:3030 near create-account fomo.test.near --initialBalance 50 --masterAccount test.near --keyPath=/near/validator_key.json
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
NEAR_ENV=local NEAR_CLI_LOCALNET_RPC_SERVER_URL=http://<ip-address>:3030 near create-account fomo.test.near --initialBalance 50 --masterAccount test.near --keyPath=/near/validator_key.json
```